# define a column that count the elements

Tags: r, dataframe, calculated-columns, performancecounter

I have a data frame:

```
xxx:
         time     x_int 
        0.000     TRUE
        0.001     TRUE
        0.002     TRUE
        0.003     FALSE
        0.004     FALSE
        0.005     TRUE
        0.006     FALSE
```

What I want to have:

```
  xxx:
    time   x_int   n
    0.000  TRUE    3
    0.001  TRUE    3
    0.002  TRUE    3
    0.003  FALSE   2
    0.004  FALSE   2
    0.006  TRUE    1
    0.007  FALSE   1
```

Therefore I want count the `TRUE` before the `FALSE` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create a grouping variable on the 'x_int', and get the get number of rows for each group (`.N`) and assign (`:=`) it to 'n'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(xxx)[, n := .N, rleid(x_int)]
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R:

```
v <- rle(d$x_int)$lengths
d$n <- rep(v, v)

#   time x_int n
#1 0.000  TRUE 3
#2 0.001  TRUE 3
#3 0.002  TRUE 3
#4 0.003 FALSE 2
#5 0.004 FALSE 2
#6 0.005  TRUE 1
#7 0.006 FALSE 1
```

---

```
d <- structure(list(time = c(0, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 
0.006), x_int = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE
)), .Names = c("time", "x_int"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```